# $.ajax is not allowing to post data of json type

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ajax

I have a rest URL where I need to post some JSON data and it would give a response as below screenshot

[image]

Now I need to consume this in my application using $http or $.ajax.I used $.ajax as below

```
var postdata = {} //whole jsonobject which is der in above screenshot      
$.ajax({
    url: "http://10.11.13.153:8081/fro?assettype=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031026",
    type: 'post',
    data: postdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {  
        console.log("response ",JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

But for this I get 200 response but I don't see that response consoled in success function.

In the network tab I see the below response

```
terms%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5B_type%5D=term&terms%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5B_id%5D=6662c0f2.e1b1ec6c.1mdln1e8h.0ibdeqc.s1nm3u.vbt90ta1civ5asp5qetu5&terms%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5B_url%5D=https%3A%2F%2F10.11.13.155%3A9445%2Fibm%2Fiis%2Figc%2F%23dossierView%2F6662c0f2.e1b1ec6c.1mdln1e8h.0ibdeqc.s1nm3u.vbt90ta1civ5asp5qetu5&terms%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5B_name%5D=Export_02
```

which is not in JSON format and not is not expected.

Below is the screenshot of headers in N/w tab

[image]

In my request headers why do I see form-urlencoded type?

I understood that it takes by default. Then how to change and make it take application/json?

Also as a try instead of JSON as datatype I changed as

```
datatype:'html'
```

Then this time I'm getting the same response as above, but this time it is getting consoled in success function. Why so? What can be done here to get the expected response in JSON format. Or anything headers that needs to be added at server side. Help or ideas please

Comment: can you try to use data : Json.stringfy(postdata)

Comment: `success: function (data) {  
        console.log("response ",JSON.stringify(responsedata));
        }` your success function returning your data as `data` but you trying to console.log `responsedata`

Comment: @Zaphiel sry I didnt noticed just typo...Even data is not getting consoled

Comment: *"`var postdata = {} //whole jsonobject which is der in above screenshot`"* That isn't a "JSON object." That's an object. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Perversely, `dataType` does not control the type of `data`; it tells jQuery what type of data you expect to get **back**. `contentType` is what tells jQuery what kind of data you're *sending*. (See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).) And when you set `contentType`, it's down to you to ensure that what you give jQuery is indeed in that format.

So in your case, you need to set `contentType` and stringify the object (see `***` lines):

```
var postdata = {} //whole jsonobject which is der in above screenshot      
$.ajax({
    url: "http://10.11.13.153:8081/fro?assettype=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031026",
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(postdata), // ***
    contentType: 'json',            // ***
    success: function (data) {  
        console.log("response ",JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

*(I also changed the content of `success` in light of your comment that using `responsedata` there was just a typo unrelated to the question.)*

If you're *also* expecting JSON back, ensure that the response has the right `Content-Type` header. (Or, as a second-class option, specify `dataType: "json"` to tell jQuery it's JSON regardless of what the server says.)